# I'm trying to implement a valid Regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the regex below to match three different type of strings. I'm having difficulty in determining where to add a case-insensitive pattern, as to match upper or lower case (eg. `re.IGNORECASE` or `([A-Za-z0-9]+))`. Should I just try something different?

```
regex = re.compile( "(%s|%s|%s)" % ( re.escape( userstring ), re.escape( userStrHEX ), re.escape( userStrASCII ) )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add it as the second argument to `re.compile()`:

```
x = re.compile("(%s|%s|%s)" % (re.escape(userstring), re.escape(userStrHEX), re.escape(userStrASCII)), re.IGNORECASE)
```

To make it a bit easier to read, we can extract the formatting arguments into a separate tuple:

```
args = (re.escape(userstring), re.escape(userStrHEX), re.escape(userStrASCII))
x = re.compile("(%s|%s|%s)" % args, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: @user706808 @unwind Or ``args = tuple(map(re.escape,(userstring,userStrHEX,userStrASCII)))``

Comment: @eyquem Thanks ... very economical way!